# How to get the row address of an Eigen::Matrix

Tags: eigen, ceres-solver

I have an
`Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> intensityEigenMat;`

I would like to pass it row by row to a ceres cost function, so I would like to access the reference to its individual rows.

I tried using:

`intensityEigenMat.row(0)`

`&intensityEigenMat.row(0)`

`&intensityEigenMat.row(0).data()`

But none of these worked. What is the right syntax please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to check the storage order option, which can be ColMajor or RowMajor.
Default is ColMajor, so you need a complex way to read the matrix row by row (including a stride factor)

If you are allowed to change the definition of your matrix to:

Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor > intensityEigenMat;

Then things will be easier, and you can use
intensityEigenMat.row(i).data() or intensityEigenMat.data()+i*rowSize

Comment: Thank you! This is what I tried but did not work, but now it worked after I added the `Eigen::RowMajor`